# При переходе по якорям мобильное меню не закрывается

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть меню с якорями, на мобильной версии всплывающее и по якорям переходит а меню не скрывается. Занимает пол экрана. Логика такая при нажатии button с атрибутом aria-expanded="false" меняет значение на "true" и у класса main-navigation появляется класс "toggled" а при повторном нажатии на кнопку меню скрывается и класс "toggled" тоже пропадает. как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на пункт меню li>a который является якорем меню тоже закрывалось. Подскажите пожалуйста только подробно я вообще сапожок в этом деле. Я так понимаю что нужно как то убирать этот "toggled" каждый раз когда нажимается пункт меню. но не знаю как это написать

```js
/**
 * File navigation.js.
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens and enables TAB key
 * navigation support for dropdown menus.
 */
( function() {
    const siteNavigation = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );

    // Return early if the navigation doesn't exist.
    if ( ! siteNavigation ) {
        return;
    }

    const button = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[ 0 ];

    // Return early if the button doesn't exist.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    const menu = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[ 0 ];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    if ( ! menu.classList.contains( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.classList.add( 'nav-menu' );
    }

    // Toggle the .toggled class and the aria-expanded value each time the button is clicked.
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        siteNavigation.classList.toggle( 'toggled' );

        if ( button.getAttribute( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'true' ) {
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    } );

    // Remove the .toggled class and set aria-expanded to false when the user clicks outside the navigation.
    document.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
        const isClickInside = siteNavigation.contains( event.target );

        if ( ! isClickInside ) {
            siteNavigation.classList.remove( 'toggled' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        }
    } );

    // Get all the link elements within the menu.
    const links = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

    // Get all the link elements with children within the menu.
    const linksWithChildren = menu.querySelectorAll( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' );

    // Toggle focus each time a menu link is focused or blurred.
    for ( const link of links ) {
        link.addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
        link.addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
    }

    // Toggle focus each time a menu link with children receive a touch event.
    for ( const link of linksWithChildren ) {
        link.addEventListener( 'touchstart', toggleFocus, false );
    }

    /**
     * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
     */
    function toggleFocus() {
        if ( event.type === 'focus' || event.type === 'blur' ) {
            let self = this;
            // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
            while ( ! self.classList.contains( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
                // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
                if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
                    self.classList.toggle( 'focus' );
                }
                self = self.parentNode;
            }
        }

        if ( event.type === 'touchstart' ) {
            const menuItem = this.parentNode;
            event.preventDefault();
            for ( const link of menuItem.parentNode.children ) {
                if ( menuItem !== link ) {
                    link.classList.remove( 'focus' );
                }
            }
            menuItem.classList.toggle( 'focus' );
        }
    }
}() );
```

```html
<div class="menu-head">
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation toggled">
<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="true">Меню</button>
<div class="menu-menu-1-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu nav-menu">
<li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="https://2a655070a20.spectrum.myjino.ru/" aria-current="page">Главная</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#school-link">О школе</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="#classes-link">Форма занятий</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19"><a href="#reviews-link">Отзывы</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-29"><a href="#teachers-link">Преподаватели</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20"><a href="#contacts-link">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Навреное нужно привести некий JavaScript код который за это отвечает, только HTML здесь никак не поможет. Ну и к WordPress это же не имеет особого отношения, кроме того что сайт на WordPress.

Comment: Добавил код который отвечает за меню. в файле navigation.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте обработчик клика после объявления переменной:

```
const menu = siteNavigation.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[ 0 ];
menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    siteNavigation.classList.remove('toggled');
})
```